# Splitting a string using lookback in PHP

Tags: php, regex

I have a product feed where the product options is formatted like this:

```
Color{1} :  Black[14], White[42] Size{2} :  Small[16], Medium[17], Large[18]
```

For my script to understand and parse the product options correctly, it needs to be in the following format:

```
Color:Black,White|Size:Small,Medium,Large
```

I started out like this to remove unnecessary information:

```
    $matches[1] = preg_replace("/\{\d{1,}\} :  /", ': ', $matches[1]);
    $matches[1] = preg_replace("/\[\d{1,}\]/", '', $matches[1]);
```

Which gives this output:

```
Color: Black, White Size: Small, Medium, Large
```

But my problem now is "how to insert a pipe before the option name, unless its only one option, or the first option". I guess I need to use some sort of lookback, but I have no idea.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, split the string into several individual options using [`preg_split()`](http://php.net/preg_split):

```
$arr = preg_split('/\s+(?=[a-z]+{\d+})/i', $str);
```

`(?=[a-z]+{\d+})` is a positive lookahead that asserts that the whitespace (`\s+`) is followed by a string of the format `<string>{xx}`. It's used here to pinpoint on which spaces the split should happen. It's important to note that the lookahead assertion is zero-width, i.e. it doesn't consume any characters at all.

Once you have the split array, loop through it, and remove `{xx}`, `[xx]` parts and whitespace:

```
foreach ($arr as &$str)
    $str = preg_replace('/(?:{\d+}|\[\d+\]|\s*)/', '', $str);
```

Join the array by `|`:

```
echo join('|', $arr);
```

Output:

```
Color:Black,White|Size:Small,Medium,Large
```

[**Demo**](https://eval.in/177066)

Answer (score 0):

This method uses only two iterations of regex substitution

First, delete all spaces along with digits

```
$re = "/(.\\d+.|[ ]+)/"; 
$str = "Color{1} :  Black[14], White[42] Size{2} :  Small[16], Medium[17], Large[18]"; 
$subst = ''; 

$result = preg_replace($re, $subst, $str);
```

Then add in the pipe

```
$re = "/([a-z])([A-Z])/";  
$subst = '\1|\2'; 

$endresult = preg_replace($re, $subst, $result);
```

Input:

```
Color{1} :  Black[14], White[42] Size{2} :  Small[16], Medium[17], Large[18]
```

Output:

```
Color:Black,White|Size:Small,Medium,Large
```

[Here's a quick demo](https://eval.in/177071)

Note: I'm assuming that the digits are always surrounded by a curly brace or a bracket without any spacing in between and that the quantity names are only alpha character (never digits).

Comment: Nice solution. Just a quick note: this would fail for cases when the quantity name includes a digit as well: for `Color33{1} :  Black[14], White[42]` this would produce `Colo1}:Black,White`.

Comment: Indeed it would! But considering how well formatted the input OP provide I **assumed** that the quantity name would all be alphas only. I had the initial regex as `[\\{\\[]\d+[\\]\\}]...` but that's really bad, so I simplified it and lost some accuracy in doing so